# how to change cell background color or image on click in ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to try ,when i click on cell then color should change and color should stay on that cell which i was clicked.till here i was success in this .But when the table is refresh then cell background color is disappear where i am wrong please help me on this i got code from apple document i use this .I miss some line in code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

      //here i create view with color for cell when cell is click this view should display as background i am write or wrong by doing this please help me here why my view is disappear when my tableview is refresh then this view is disapper from cell i want to stay that place till user not click other cell&mt tableview is grouped tableview.
       UIView *v = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
       v.layer.cornerRadius =6.0f;
       v.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
       cell.selectedBackgroundView = v;
       }
     return cell;
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row%1 == 0) {
        UIColor *altCellColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2 alpha:0.1];
        cell.backgroundColor = altCellColor;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retained your selected row on refresh then you can save your selected indexPath and use following method:

```
NSIndexPath *rowToSelect; //save your selected indexPath

[myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:rowToSelect animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone;
[myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:rowToSelect atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNon animate:YES];
```

Comment: hi friend where to use this code i ewrite in did seleted method but it crash when cell is selected

Comment: You should save your indexPath in didSelect method and call above method in cellForRowAtIndexPath.and Can you please show your crash log?

Comment: i am making spliteview application in ipad left view is tableview and right side view all data entry are showing when i adding new date that time my selected cell color are refresh and disappear from cell what to now

Comment: friend my left side all list of page name are showing on cell when i click any cell then right side open according to that page name and cell color should stay even i add new record they not effect on this when i delete or add cell should stay there color

Comment: Your number of rows are changing in tableview?

Comment: i have 3 section and 5 row in first setion i have 1row, second section 3row and third section 1row